# Datagridview e checkbox - comportamento estranho.

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

Tenho uma datagridview com umas checkboxes. 
tenho este código:

```
Private Sub DataGridView2_CellMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView2.CellMouseClick
    If e.ColumnIndex > 1 Then
        DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Mas a checkbox apenas fica "checkada" quando o focus sai dela. Ou seja apenas fica "checkada" quando clico noutro objecto no projecto.

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece por que sempre que você clica numa célula, e esta estiver numa coluna com o index maior que 1:

```
If e.ColumnIndex > 1 Then 
    DataGridView2(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value = True
End If
```

o seu código esta fazendo com que a célula fique com o valor ckeckbox como true sempre.

Comment: Já resolvi, mas obrigado na mesma.

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi.
Estava a usar a acção "cellvaluechanged" e esta tambem nao estava a ser chamada no devido tempo.

O problema é que no vb quando usamos checkboxes e datagridviews, ele apenas efectua o "check" quando fazermos focus a outro objecto.

Para resolver isso apenas pus uma linha de código onde faço focus a outro objecto e pronto, as checkboxes já funcionam.